# c# oracle: get RowId aftert Insert

Tags: c#, oracle, insert, rowid

Dears all,

I'm trying to return the **Oracle RowId** after an insert but the result is always null (even if the Insert is correct).
Why? What's wrong?

Here below you can find the code:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.AddParameter("ROWINSERTED", string.Empty, DBTypes.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.InputOutput);
cmd.CommandText = $@"INSERT INTO EQUIPVAR(ID_VAR, ID_QU, XTGYREVAVALUE) VALUES(1, 1, 'TEST') RETURNING rowid INTO :ROWINSERTED";                
var res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

I'm waiting the result inside the parameter **ROWINSERTED**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you need rowid? Does the table itself doesn't have unique reference? If not - it should.

Comment: Unfortunately the table has not a unique reference and I can't change it....

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with Dapper (nuget package):

```
DynamicParameters parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("out_id", dbType: DbType.Decimal, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
database.Execute($@"INSERT INTO EQUIPVAR(ID_VAR, ID_QU, XTGYREVAVALUE) VALUES(1, 1, 'TEST') RETURNING rowid INTO :out_id", parameters);
int id = (int)parameters.Get<decimal>("out_id");
```